# JPQL navigate through several nested objects for comparison

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, jpql

So, I'm creating a search function to find a post containing bookitems where one bookitem contains a book with a specific title.

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN p.books b JOIN FETCH b.book bo WHERE bo.title LIKE '%hi%'
```

where books is a list of BookItems containing one Book each

And that works if I'm running the JPQL from netbeans towards the server but when i use the same query with the EntityManager i recieve an exception that bo after b.book was an unexpected symbol. But i really don't now how else to do it.

**EDIT**
Aditional info:
stacktrace:

```
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN p.books b JOIN FETCH b.book bo WHERE bo.title LIKE :title], line 1, column 54: unexpected token [bo].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(80@[()* loopback of 477:9: (node= join )*])
```

if i try with fetch after first JOIN it prints the same error but on b instead of bo

Code when running JPQL:

```
query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN p.books b JOIN FETCH b.book bo WHERE bo.title LIKE :title", Post.class);
query.setParameter("title", "%"+searchString+"%");
posts = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Please show the code where you run the JPQL query.

Comment: Post the complete and exact stack trace. My guess is that it's complaining about the fetch clause: you try to fetch b.book without fetching b.

Comment: Change it to `select p from Post p join p.books b where b.book.title like :title`, do you really need a join fetch when you select `p` and you don't join fetch books?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to answer my own question, I apparently had the wrong idea about JOIN FETCH and didn't understand how it worked. The correct query was

```
SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN p.books b JOIN b.book bo WHERE bo.title LIKE :title
```

As i wanted all data and didn't realize that JOIN FETCH only chose the data specified. I need join because I want all data to be fetched.

Comment: Your description is WRONG! All data would not be fetched if you write `JOIN`, it depends on mapping, and lazyness of the relationships. If you want all data eagerly fetched use `select  from Post join fetch p.books b join fetch b.books bo where bo.title like :title`, this will eagerly fetch `p`, `books` and `book` even if the associations are annotated as LAZY.

Comment: Ok, i read up some more about it and it turns out you are correct Although as I wrote in my question, that did work perfectly running straight in Netbeans but running it in the code would generate an exception saying JOIN FETCH doesn't handle aliases. Join fetch does not in any way represent a SQL JOIN. So I'm puzzled why this even works in netbeans. If you know, please let me know.